# How to repeat a code in matlab, and export each of them to excel in separate columns?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have this code, and I want to run this code for 100 times. I want c and d be exported to excel with a blank column space with the previous c and d data. For example I want the next c and d go to the columns D and E in excel.

```
n=300;
a=mvnrnd([0 0], [1 0.5;0.5 1],n);
c=a(:,1);
d=a(:,2);
xlswrite('mani_data',c,'rawdata','A1');
xlswrite('mani_data',d,'rawdata','B1');
```

Comment: you have to change 'A1' and 'B1' in the `for` loop on each iteration. Look at this, `char('A'+1)='B'`. From this MATLAB operation, you should be able to get started. Also, since you want to run 100 iterations, your excel column will go like: `AA, AB, AC, ..., AZ`. Take care of that too.